# Css issues with Jquery Dialogue Box in IE 7,8

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am using Jquery Dialog box for a cv registration form on my website [job website](http://wehavethecandidate.co.uk/) , the dialogue box comes up when send us your CV [image] is clicked on the website, i have customised the  original css of jquery dialogue box to suit the client needs , the css works fine in all browsers apart from IE8 , 7. I just cant find a way to figure out why the css is not working , i have spend several hours without any success, 
Can anyone suggest me or provide any assistance on it 
Thanks

Comment: Could you specify your CSS. and mark what is not working on IE8 and IE7

Comment: dialogue box which opens up when clicking on send cv image on the website mentioned above in IE 7,8 , css can be inspected using f12 developer tools available on IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. your modal window is using an iframe, use `border:0` because IE is
   rendering the iframe with a border.
2. IE doesn't know how to make an iframe background transparent or
   doesn't inherit it properly. I don't have time to look into a proper
   fix for that, but the easy fix is to add the background color to
   your `.modal` class in your style.css. Just match that nice blue and
   you'll be good to go.

Comment: border is already set to 0 , and added bg color too but no change in display :(